# getting undisplayed portion of slider/linearlayout to not resize

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-linearlayout

I have a basic slider with two linear layouts. (Here are the relevant details of the layout:

```
<RelativeLayout>
<LinearLayout id:"left" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"> ... </LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout id:"right" android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
<ImageView id:"first"></ImageView>
<ImageView id:"second"></ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

both `left` and `right` have children views. By default, left is visible. When the user slides to the left, `right` becomes visible. The children of `right` are two image views: `first` and `second`.

My problem is, as the user slides to the left, I need `second` to become visible. And then as the user slides further, I need `first` to become visible.

Right now, it is more of a pulling effect. What I want is a revealing/pealing effect: As I pull away `left` for it to reveal that image `second` was there all along; then as I pull some more for it to reveal that image `first` was also always there all along.

Anyone who has GMail on the iPhone can see the pealing effect.

Another related problem with my design is that as I pull `left`, `first` grows from a dot into a full image; as I pull some more, `right` does the same thing. The images should not grow (in radius) from a dot. Though off screen, they should be full-size so that they appear as if growing from a slab into a rectangle; as in

```
  |
 ||
|||
```

as I pull to the left.

Comment: I fix the aspect ratio problem using `android:scaleType="matrix"`

Answer (score 2):

so I solved my problem by add to LinearLayout `android:scaleType="fitXY"` and by giving fixed width to both ImageViews. I hope the next person finds this useful.

P.S. I saw that GMail did it on iPhone but not on android. Well, GMail, now you know how to do it. :)